# get value using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am trying to fetch a value from the following html snippet using DOMDocument:

```
<h3>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">€ 

    <meta itemprop="price" content="465.0000">465
</h3>
```

I need to fetch the value 465 from this code snippet. To avail this I am using the following code:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $h) {
  foreach($h->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $p) {

    if($h->getAttribute('itemprop') == 'price') {
        foreach($h->childNodes as $child) {
            $name = $child->nodeValue;
                        echo $name;
                        $name = preg_replace('/[^0-9\,]/', '', $name);
                      //  $name = number_format($name, 2, ',', ' ');
                        if (strpos($name,',') == false) 
                        {
                         $name = $name .",00";
                        }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

But this code is not fetching the value...can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop, you're pointing in the wrong object:

```
foreach($h->childNodes as $child) {
//      ^ its not supposed to be `$h`
```

You should point to `$p` instead.

After that just use your current condition, if it satisfies, then loop all the child nodes:

```
$price = '';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $h) {

    foreach($h->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $p) {

        if($p->getAttribute('itemprop') === 'price') {
            foreach($h->childNodes as $c) {
                if($c->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                    $price .= trim($c->textContent);
                }
            }
            if(strpos($price, ',') === false) {
                $price .= ',00';
            }
        }



    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/cBBouD)

Another way is to use xpath queries:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$meta = $xpath->query('//h3/meta[@itemprop="price"]');
if($meta->length > 0) { // found
    $price = trim($xpath->evaluate('string(./following-sibling::text()[1])', $meta->item(0)));
    if(strpos($price, ',') === false) { $price .= ',00'; }
    $currency = $xpath->evaluate('string(./preceding-sibling::meta[@itemprop="priceCurrency"]/following-sibling::text()[1])', $meta->item(0));
    $price = "{$currency} {$price}";
    echo $price;
}
```

[Out](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/1djIaw)

Comment: @Ghost...I have tried the following code...still it does not work...foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $h) {
  foreach($h->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $p) {

    if($p->getAttribute('itemprop') == 'price') {
  foreach($p->childNodes as $child) {


$name = $child->nodeValue;

}

}

}

}

Comment: @user3305327 check out my revision, plus i added a sample output

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid HTML. Where is the closing tag for meta? This is why you get the results you see.

To find what you are looking for you can use xpath:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($yourHTML);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//meta[@itemprop='price']");
echo $elements->item(0)->textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, like this:

```
  var priceCurrency = $('meta[itemprop="priceCurrency"]').attr("content");
  var price = $('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr("content");
  alert(priceCurrency + " " + price);
```

---

Outputs:

```
EUR 465.0000
```

---

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/XbWWRE)